# What Rbac action/permission would allow Azure App Service Network Access Restrictions

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Which Rbac action would allow Azure App Service Network --> Access Restrictions ? We dont want every user to have auth to set/unset ip-rules using 'Networking --- Access Restrictions' for app-services.

Comment: Hi, if my solution helps you, can you mark it as the answer of the question?:) [Link abour how to mark answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to change the network access and I can get the action information from the brower.

[image]

So the action should between this:

[image]

You can use a custom role,

```
 $role = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name "Virtual Machine Contributor"

 $role.Id =$null

 $role.Name = "testcustombowman"

 $role.Description = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"

 $role.Actions.RemoveRange(0,$role.Actions.Count)

 $role.Actions.add("Microsoft.Web/sites/config/Read")

 $role.AssignableScopes.Clear()

 $role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx")

 New-AzRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

Have a look of this [Offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#built-in-role-descriptions), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#built-in-role-descriptions).

But I still recommend you to use a simple way, directly give the relevant people only Read permissions.

It is highly recommended that you use the simple method, `add role assignment` -> `Select Reader` -> `Select User`

As you can see, the relevant users are unable to operate the settings you said in my case.

[image]